# JS Game (Duck Hunt) Adding .png files to certain levels

Tags: javascript

Im trying to add different characters to different levels in the classic game Duck Hunt. I got the original source code form git hub (https://github.com/MattSurabian/DuckHunt-JS) and now have 3 levels and created different .png files for the levels by adding them to the css however not Im sure where in the JS scripting to adjust the code so each level has a different charcater? Im guessing I will need an if statment using each level ID.

this is where its picking up the ducks (duckA / B) in the JS

```
{var e=t%2===0?"duckA":"duckB";this.duckMax++,this.liveDucks.push(new Duck(this.duckMax.toString(),e,this.level.speed,this.playfield).fly())}},
killDuck:function(t){this.levelStats.ducksKilled+=1,this.liveDucks=_(this.liveDucks).reject(function(e){return e.id===t.id}),
0===this.liveDucks.length&&this.playfield.trigger("wave:end",this.curWave)},
drawDucks:function(){var t="",e=this.level.ducks*this.curWave-this.levelStats.ducksKilled;e=e>25?25:e;
```

And these are the Levels

```
levels=[
{id:1,title:"Level 1",waves:1,ducks:10,pointsPerDuck:100,speed:2,bullets:15,time:25},
{id:2,title:"Level 2",waves:1,ducks:10,pointsPerDuck:150,speed:4,bullets:15,time:20},
{id:3,title:"Level 3",waves:1,ducks:10,pointsPerDuck:200,speed:6,bullets:15,time:18}],
```

I want to be able to have duckC / D on level 2 (id 2) and duckE / F on level 3 (id 3).... Can anyone help?

EDIT:

So I have adjusted the sections of code in duckhunt.min.js as follows however only the default two ducks are loading? Any idea why?

```
Duck.prototype.hatch=function(){
$('<div id="'+this.id+'" class="duck1 '+this.className+'"></div>').appendTo(this.game),
this.DOM=$("#"+this.id),
this.bindEvents()
$('<div id="'+this.id+'" class="duck2 '+this.className+'"></div>').appendTo(this.game),
this.DOM=$("#"+this.id),
this.bindEvents()},

releaseDucks:function(){
for(var t=0;t<this.level.ducks;t++)
{var e=t%2===0?"duckA":"duckB";
this.duckMax++,
this.liveDucks.push(new Duck(this.duckMax.toString(),e,this.level.speed,this.playfield).fly())
}
{var e=t%2===0?"duckC":"duckD";
this.duckMax++,
this.liveDucks.push(new Duck(this.duckMax.toString(),e,this.level.speed,this.playfield).fly())
}
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in `duck.js` where the DOM element for the duck is being created

```
Duck.prototype.hatch = function(){

    $('<div id="'+this.id+'" class="duck '+this.className+'"></div>').appendTo(this.game);
    this.DOM = $("#"+this.id);
    this.bindEvents();
};
```

The Duck constructor is passed 'duckA' or 'duckB' via `this.className` for the two variations of duck built into the game, so modify `duckhunt.js` to factor in the level data instead:

```
releaseDucks : function(){
    for(var i=0;i<this.level.ducks;i++){
        var duckClass = "duck"+this.level.id; //This is different!
        this.duckMax++;
        this.liveDucks.push(new Duck(this.duckMax.toString(),duckClass,this.level.speed,this.playfield).fly());
    }
},
```

Then, title your classes `duck1`, `duck2`, `duck3`, ... and style them like in the original repo!

Comment: Hi I have updated my orignal post I have added the ducks C/D into the css and updated the sections of code however the defualt ducks are only still loading, could you help at little further? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Dave Hey, make sure you modify the value of `e` (var duckClass) to be based off of the level, like in my example. You'll find this a lot easier, however, if you work with the source files and not the minified version.

Comment: Hi J4G I still cant seem to show any other .png files? And not sure why when I only change the duckhunt.min.js can see changes? Is it possible for us to talk in a chat or something?

Comment: Hi J4G I think im nearly there! I now have it running from the main scripts however where is the duck class located? Once I know this i can add the duck2 etc (I can only find Ducks in the css)?

Comment: Do you see `.duckA` and `.duckB` in `style.css`? Add classes like those, but called `duck1` and so on.

Comment: done that but then how do I add the class into the js script? I can get the one class working but not the others?

Comment: Look at my second block of code. You're assigning the variable `duckClass` to a string called `duck1` for the first level, `duck2` for the second level, and so forth. When you run the line with `new Duck()` it gives the duck.js the name of your class which will be automatically added. I'm sorry - I really don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: No I complety understand what you are saying and have updated my css with .duck and .duck2 however it keeps using the first .png file (.duck) on the second level?

Comment: Pardon me - I made it mistake. It should be `this.level.id`. I've updated my answer.